# Is there a black theme for Dreamweaver?

Tags: dreamweaver, color-scheme

Does anyone a black theme addon for dreamweaver something like this:

[image]

Comment: Are you asking for an xml config file for dreamweaver? the one that goes in the codecoloring folder in the configuration folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a question about PHP at all. This is a question only related to Dreamweaver. I don't own the software myself, but there's probably something like... Preferences > Editor > Colors where you can change the background color or select a theme.

Try:
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/617313?tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

`Edit->Preferences->Code Coloring` select a `Default background` then scroll down to the PHP selection and `Edit Coloring Scheme`.